# Increase PHP value +1 in jQuery (like button)

Tags: jquery

```
<iniput type="button" id="like">
<span id="like_num"><?PHP echo $like;?></span>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#like").click(function(){
  $('#like_num').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });     
  });
});
```

I have a like button, I need to increase the php $like value +1 after it click in Jquery.

I use jquery post, but I don't want to call back(output), it kinds of wast query... I just want to add 1, so user know they successful clicked.

Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

If it doen't need to be communicated back to the server, I guess this will work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#like").click(function(){
     var count = parseInt($('#like_num').text());
     $('#like_num').text(count + 1);     
  });
});
```

This assumes you know $like is always an integer, and that you update the like count on the server in a seperate call.

Edit:
Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AJxKb/

In the case it needs to go to the server too:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#like").click(function(){
         var count = parseInt($('#like_num').text());
         $('#like_num').text(count + 1); 

         $.ajax("http://yourdomain.com/update_like.php").done(function () {
             //You can update the counter here too instead of assuming it was a success
          })
      });
    });
```

And the in that update_like.php file:

```
<?php 
  $like = GetNumberOfLikesFromWhereeverTheyAreStored();

  $like = $like + 1;

  StoreTheNewNumberWhereeverTheyComeFrom($like);
  //Be careful to handle several request updating the counter simultanously

?>
```

Will that help?

Comment: <?PHP $like=3;?>its not working when I use <?PHP echo $like;?>

Comment: Not sure what you mean... The PHP code is run on the server, meaning the server will fill in whatever number your $like variable holds... When it is ready and it is received by your browser, the <?PHP echo $like;?> will be gone and is replaced by a number (I took 3 as an example in my Fiddle)

Comment: I did the test, but it didn't work, let me try few more to see what happen

Comment: I think he's suggesting that it does need to go to the server, but that it doesnt need to wait for the POST callback (so, assume it's successful)

Comment: $like=1980; when I click it become 2

Comment: is any way can do it without go to the server?

Comment: Not sure, that all depends on your implementation and what the application has to do... You use PHP so I thought you were doing some serverside stuff anyway... If the number of likes need to be stored over many users or browsers or days you need to store it somewhere (usually on the server), if it's just for this once and you never leave the page, that you can maybe use local storage or something..? If you explain your goal a little more, maybe we can help better...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var like=Number("<?PHP echo $like;?>");
    $('#like_num').text(like);

    $("#like").click(function(){

        var like=Number("<?PHP echo $like+1;?>");
        $('#like_num').empty().append(like); 
            //than disable the button and post update the database     
    });
});
```

Hey guys, I have find a solution, do it without post back.

I have remove `<?PHP echo $like;?>` from `<span></span>`

than I use jquery `text()` on it first

when user click, it `empty append <?PHP $like+1;?>`

Than disable the button, post the data and update the db